# quickly run is not working

Tags: python, quickly

This is my terminal answer after quickly run command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/browser", line 35, in import browser
File "/home/alen/browser/browser/init.py", line 12, in from browser import BrowserWindow
File "/home/alen/browser/browser/BrowserWindow.py", line 32
self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

There are another two lines of code in `BrowserWindow.py` I put:

```
def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget): print "refresh";
```

for my button to work.

What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you add more details? Not sure but could check you indent if it's correct. BTW, you can't mix TAB with SPACES in python.

Comment: I would be glad if  you can help me more then expected. What is indent?

Comment: It is a part of python code or something  like protocol? How can I fix that? I made quickly run project named browser. Had made a button for refreshing: What I added above is python code in BrowserWindow.py as it is shown in some tutorial.

Comment: Could you copy-paste the full code in the file to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **2.5. Indenting Code**
>
> Python functions have no explicit begin or end, and no curly braces to
>   mark where the function code starts and stops. The only delimiter is a
>   colon (:) and the indentation of the code itself.
>
> Example 2.5. Indenting the buildConnectionString Function
>
> ```
> def buildConnectionString(params):
>     """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters.
>
>     Returns string."""
>     return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])
> ```

**Source:** [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html)

So the indent in Python is those **4 spaces** at beginning of code lines in function definition,class definition, condition block...

Basically, you have the indent inside the function which does not correspond the indent before it.

Comment: tnx. the indent was problem!!!